# Search results including metadata keywords always "hidden"

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, permissions, mms

One of our 2013 sites (dedicated to hosting a large document library) has developed a weird quirk in its search. When you search within a library to find documents related to a managed metadata keyword, the results page always says "Some files might be hidden. [Include] these in your search." You have to click the "Include" link before anything is shown. I'm reasonably certain this is not permissions related on the MMS side because I just fixed that issue (the hidden taxonomy list had its permissions blown away for some reason), but I don't know what other factors may be involved. Has anyone seen this behavior before? The only post online I can find is a person asking the question and a bunch of people saying "Me too!" But there's no actual answer.

Comment: Strange problem. I am experiencing the same issue. Although, searching from my account is fine. If I search from any other users account, I have to display the hidden results to see the search results. This is only the case when searching within the document library. If I search he entire site, I see the results. Sorry I don't have the answer to this problem. I can however confirm it is a problem and I have checked permissions. I have checked a users account that has identical permissions to myself. I can see the search items, and everyone else has to "unhide" them.